# Array is not updating within a nested firestore get

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am little confused on why an array is not updating when I resolve a promise that contains Firestore nested get.

The code is below:

```
let userArray = [];
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    channelPaticipationRef
      .where('channel', '==', channel.id)
      .get()
      .then(participationSnapshot => {
        participationSnapshot.forEach(participationDoc => {
          const participation = participationDoc.data();
          participation.id = participationDoc.id;
          if (participation.user != userId) {
            usersRef
              .doc(participation.user)
              .get()
              .then(user => {
                if (user.data()) {
                  const userData = user.data();
                  userArray = [
                    ...userArray,
                    {
                      userId: userData.id,
                      userFirstName: userData.firstName,
                      userLastName: userData.lastName,
                      userIsOnline: userData.isOnline,
                      userProfilePictureURL: userData.profilePictureURL,
                      userLastTimestamp: userData.lastOnlineTimestamp,
                    },
                  ];
                  console.log(1, userArray)
                }
              })
              .catch(error => console.log(error));
          }
          console.log(2, userArray)
        });
        console.log(3, userArray)
        resolve(userArray);
      });
  });
```

In the console it returns

```
2 []
2 []
3 []
1 [{…}]
1 (2) [{…}, {…}]
```

and the promise returns an empty array

If I am pushing or updating the array using a spread operator, why is it not registering?

Comment: I think the issue is more due to the fact that promise callback execute asynchronously than anything else.  `then`, and any method that returns a promise, will do so immediately, and the callback will be invoked some time later.  Your logs are simply executing before the promises resolve.  Try adding more logging throughout your code to see what's actually going on.

Comment: @DougStevenson I just updated the post. It looks like you are right. I will try and debug based on the findings. Maybe needs some awaits.